# How to fill this form using mechanicalSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

I need to to enter the login to this page via mechanicalsoup. The input is username and password.

```
<div id='credentials' class='loggedout'>
    <input name='username' placeholder='Username' type='text'  id='username' 
    size='30' maxlength='60'>
    <input name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password' 
    id='password' size='30'autocomplete='off'maxlength='60'onfocus='if(this.value=="Password")this.value="";'>
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
I would be more helpful if I could know to how to select this input form.
Any thoughts are hearty appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can't use beautifulsoup to fill out a form. Beautifulsoup is for parsing HTML/XML/etc.

Comment: use requests - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master